# Стоит ли использовать бесплатные версии ПО от Microsoft для учащихся?

Tags: лицензирование

Мне так кажется, что таким способом, они готовят себе в будущем больше специалистов по ихним продуктов?

Comment: Сплошной ЗОГ мерещится всем и везде.  
Им не нужно готовить специалистов. У них есть специалисты в достаточном количестве. Раздача студентам бесплатных/дешевых/урезанных версий - это популярная и логичная практика, которая связана с тем, что а) у студента нет денег б) он даже не зарабатывает на этом в) компания косвенно на этом заработает репутации или денег за те же работы студентов г) они вообще заинтересованы не в оплате за этот продукт и количестве специалистов, а продвижении производной от этого продукта (например, какого-нибудь Azure) и больше свободного ПО им только на руку.

Comment: Я это и имел ввиду специалистов), людей, которые будут использовать продукт, даже потому, что они учились работали на нем долгое время.

Comment: @Etki, по-моему, это не «зог», а элементарные «капиталистические» соображения: больше специалистов → больше продаж → выше прибыль. связь «больше специалистов → больше продаж» проистекает из тех же соображений, когда ими руководствуются клиенты: больше специалистов на рынке труда → выгоднее нанимать именно их → выгоднее покупать то, что лучше знают эти специалисты.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Конечно они для себя это делают, готовят почву в будущем), но почему бы и не использовать в своих целях?

Comment: ну да, та же мысь

Comment: если п.о. под свободной лицензией — согласен. только к [бес]платности это не имеет прямого отношения.

Comment: Сам спросил, сам ответил? Смешно.